# Most efficient way of converting a Quarto document to a presentation

Tags: computational-statistics, reporting, teaching

I currently have a large body of statistics lecture notes that I wrote in Rmarkdown/Quarto document format, and I am looking to convert these notes to Quarto presentations in the simplest way possible.  The lecture notes are quite detailed and students can use them as a reference, and the slides I am hoping to use instead for in-class teaching.  Currently I lecture right off of the lecture note HTML, but feedback from previous years suggests that slides may be better for lecture.

Is there an easy way to generate slides off my existing notes?  Perhaps adding lots of subsections to the notes and recompile as a presentation?  Is there a good way to sync a documents with a presentation so that the content in the presentation is updated with changes in the notes?  Thanks in advance for any advice